# Does code on a Google sheet runs locally or on a Google server? - UrlFetchApp returns empty

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to make a connection from a Google sheet to my company's Jira site, without much success for now. I have tried many things and read many posts where I see many people having issues when it comes to UrlFetchApp. Every time I tried the connection it returns empty.

What I think it is happening is that my company Jira is behind a firewall and we connect to it either from the office or though a VPN when we are outside the office.

Under this circumstances, if the code I have on a sheet runs on some remote Google server, the connection to Jira will fail since that server is not going through our vpn.

If the code runs locally on the sheet, then it should connect fine.

So my question is that... Does code on a Google sheet runs locally or on a Google server?

I guess it is the later rather than the former but just asking to confirm.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Miguel.

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script is a cloud based solution. Your onpremise JIRA server won't be accessible.

Google once upon a time supported connection through firewalls with the Secure Data Connector but this has now been discontinued.

Best option is to have a local solution extract and deploy a reporting format to be consumed via Google Drive if you need Apps Script access.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. I see they are also deprecating OAuth. Do you know of any other possibility?