# Google Apps Script fetch data from private network (vpn)

Tags: google-apps-script, fetch, vpn, jira-rest-api, private-network

I've tried to do use Jira API for my application, but Jira is placed like a private network.

UrlFetchApp.fetch responds with a DNS error.

How do I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script is a cloud based solution. Your onpremise JIRA server won't be accessible.

Google once upon a time supported connection through firewalls with the Secure Data Connector but this has now been discontinued.

Best option is to have a local solution extract and deploy a reporting format to be consumed via Google Drive if you need Apps Script access.

from: [Does code on a Google sheet runs locally or on a Google server? - UrlFetchApp returns empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461797/does-code-on-a-google-sheet-runs-locally-or-on-a-google-server-urlfetchapp-re)